# WebRTC change bandwidth receiving InvalidModificationError on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc

I'm trying to modify the bandwidth by following this sample: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/bandwidth/

However, I'm receiving this error on Chrome.

**errorInvalidModificationError: Read-only field modified in setParameters()**

Firefox changed the bandwidth successfully. A few months ago, it worked properly on Chrome too. Suddenly receiving this error, I've googled around and still didn't find any solution for this, may I know how to fix this error? Thank you.

```
var bandwidth = 500;

// Loop through each track                          
var i;
for (i = 0; i < peers[peer_id].getSenders().length; i++) { 
    var sender = peers[peer_id].getSenders()[i];

    if(sender.track.kind === "video"){
        var parameters = sender.getParameters();

        if (!parameters.encodings) {
          parameters.encodings = [{}];
        }

        parameters.encodings = [{}];

        parameters.encodings[0].maxBitrate = bandwidth * 1000;

        sender.setParameters(parameters).then(success, error);

        function success(){
            console.log("bandwidth success adjust");
        };

        function error(err){
            console.log("bandwidth error"+err);
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: Try removing the second `parameters.encodings = [{}];`.

Comment: It worked, thank you so much @jib, you're really great.This is my mistake where I'm not familiar with this line "if (!parameters.encodings)" and didn't know that this is the main cause of the issue. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the second `parameters.encodings = [{}];` It accidentally erases all properties of the first encoding in `encodings`, some of which are meant to be read-only and aren't allowed to be modified.

The [pc.setParameters()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCRtpSender/setParameters) method requires its input to have come from [pc.getParameters()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCRtpSender/getParameters) effectively, and only certain `encodings` properties are allowed to be modified.

It was designed to be a transaction:

```
const parameters = pc.getParemeters();
// modify certain parameters only
await pc.setParemeters(parameters);
```

This is enforced by `getParameters()` including a [parameters.transactionId](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCRtpSender/setParameters#Parameters), which `setParameters()` checks for. If it or certain other properties that are meant to be read-only have been modified, you'll get `InvalidModificationError`.

#### Firefox is too lenient

Firefox implements a very early version of the API that is too lenient. [Bug 1401592](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1401592) tracks fixing this.

The following line is only needed because of Firefox:

```
  if (!parameters.encodings) {
    parameters.encodings = [{}];
  }
```

Because only in Firefox would `encodings` returned from `getParameters()` ever be empty.

In Chrome and the spec, `encodings` is guaranteed to be present and include at minimum one item.

Comment: Hi @jib Now, I finally understand the " if (!parameters.encodings)". Thank you for your detailed explanations.